# Multiple targets for project in xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am using xcode 7.3.1. After pod update, it's showing multiple project target in the project having same details without any change. How can I fix this? If I delete any one of these, xcode crashes and when we reopen even the other option comes in red and we dont have any project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to delete the workspace file and the pod directory, and re-launch a `pod install` ? The workspace file does not hold any important information to be retained in CocoaPods.

If you have the same problem after regenerating, it means there is an error in the Pod file.